# Using excel find with timeseries

Tags: vba, excel, find

I have a problem with the `.find` command. I want to create a macro to copy a range and paste it after a specific cell found with the `find` command (offset to move the active cell to the data value):

```
Sub value()
Dim today As String
Dim lookfor As Range

Sheets(1).Range("C3:C19").Copy
today = "11.nov"

Set lookfor = Cells.Find(What:=today, _
            After:=ActiveCell, _
            LookIn:=xlValues, _
            LookAt:=xlPart, _
            SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, _
            SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
            MatchCase:=False, _
            SearchFormat:=False).Activate

lookfor.Offset(rowOffset:=1, columnOffset:=3).Paste
End Sub
```

Comment: Your code seem to do the trick, just change `otsitav.Offset(...)` to `lookfor.Offset(...)`

Comment: That was translation mistake. Sorry for that but the code still gives error nr91: Object variable or With block variable not set. I tried to make the workbook a object but it still gave errors

Comment: Get rid of the `.Activate` at the end of `Set lookfor` and your code should work properly! ;)

Comment: @R3uK has your answer.  Using `.Activate` at the end doesn't actually `Set` anything. You're activating a cell, but not using it or something. Change that to `.Row`, `.Column`, `.Address` or whatever you may need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In facts, you have to check if there is a result for the `Find` method with `If Not LookFor Is Nothing Then` before working with it.

So my guess is that the `Find` method didn't find anything for the value you were looking for.

Here is your amended code :

```
Sub test_Veiko_Aunapuu()
Dim FirstAddress As String, _
    ToDay As String, _
    LookFor As Range

ToDay = "11.nov"

Sheets(1).Activate
Sheets(1).Range("C3:C19").Copy

With Sheets(1).Cells
    '----First, define properly the Find method
    Set LookFor = .Find(What:=ToDay, _
                After:=ActiveCell, _
                LookIn:=xlValues, _
                LookAt:=xlPart, _
                SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, _
                SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                MatchCase:=False, _
                SearchFormat:=False)

    If Not LookFor Is Nothing Then
    '----If there is a result,
        FirstAddress = LookFor.Address
        'LookFor.Activate
        MsgBox "The row containing " & ToDay & " is : " & LookFor.Row
        'Keep looking with FindNext method : Not usefull for your example
        Do
            '-------------------------------------------------------------
            '----Place instructions to execute on the matched cell/row/...
            LookFor.Offset(rowOffset:=1, columnOffset:=3).Paste

            '-------------------------------------------------------------
            Set LookFor = .FindNext(LookFor)
        'Loop and keep looking until you find again the first result
        Loop While Not LookFor Is Nothing And LookFor.Address <> FirstAddress
    Else
    '----If there is no results, say it
        MsgBox "No matches were found for : " & ToDay, vbCritical + vbOKOnly, "No results"
    End If
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Removed the Activate but still same error. The problem is that it doesn't set the cell value. @BruceWayne I tried to set it to adress but it said type mismatch (i checked the spelling).

Comment: @VeikoAunapuu : I edit my answer that will probably help you identify your issue! If there is no matches, try to change `Find` arguments, starting with `LookIn:=xlFormulas`. Let me know! ;)

Comment: Tnahk you @R3uK  wrestled with this problem for a long time